# Selecting features in python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, k-means, pca, feature-selection

I am trying to do this algorithm http://venom.cs.utsa.edu/dmz/techrep/2007/CS-TR-2007-011.pdf

```
import pandas as pd
import pathlib
import gaitrec
from tsfresh import extract_features
from collections import defaultdict
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import euclidean_distances

class PFA(object):
    def __init__(self, n_features, q=None):
        self.q = q
        self.n_features = n_features

    def fit(self, X):
        if not self.q:
            self.q = X.shape[1]
        pca = PCA(n_components=self.q).fit(X)
        A_q = pca.components_.T
        kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=self.n_features).fit(A_q)
        clusters = kmeans.predict(A_q)
        cluster_centers = kmeans.cluster_centers_
        dists = defaultdict(list)
        for i, c in enumerate(clusters):
            dist = euclidean_distances(A_q[i, :].reshape(1,-1), cluster_centers[c, :].reshape(1,-1))[0][0]
            dists[c].append((i, dist))
        self.indices_ = [sorted(f, key=lambda x: x[1])[0][0] for f in dists.values()]
        self.features_ = X[:, self.indices_]


p = pathlib.Path(gaitrec.__file__).parent
dataset_file = p / 'DatasetC' / 'subj_001' / 'walk0' / 'subj_0010.csv'
read_csv = pd.read_csv(dataset_file, sep=';', decimal='.', names=['time','x','y', 'z', 'id'])
read_csv['id'] = 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(read_csv)
    extracted_features = extract_features(read_csv, column_id="id", column_sort="time")
    features_withno_nanvalues = extracted_features.dropna(how='all', axis=1)
    print(features_withno_nanvalues)
    X = features_withno_nanvalues.to_numpy()
    pfa = PFA(n_features=2274, q=1)
    pfa.fit(X)
    Y = pfa.features_
    print(Y) #feature extracted
    column_indices = pfa.indices_ #index of the features
    print(column_indices)

C:\Users\Thund\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe C:/Users/Thund/Desktop/RepoBitbucket/Gaitrec/gaitrec/extraction.py
      time         x         y         z  id
0        0 -0.833333  0.416667 -0.041667   0
1        1 -0.833333  0.416667 -0.041667   0
2        2 -0.833333  0.416667 -0.041667   0
3        3 -0.833333  0.416667 -0.041667   0
4        4 -0.833333  0.416667 -0.041667   0
...    ...       ...       ...       ...  ..
1337  1337 -0.833333  0.416667  0.083333   0
1338  1338 -0.833333  0.416667  0.083333   0
1339  1339 -0.916667  0.416667  0.083333   0
1340  1340 -0.958333  0.416667  0.083333   0
1341  1341 -0.958333  0.416667  0.083333   0

[1342 rows x 5 columns]
Feature Extraction: 100%|██████████| 3/3 [00:04<00:00,  1.46s/it]
C:\Users\Thund\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sklearn\decomposition\_pca.py:461: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide
  explained_variance_ = (S ** 2) / (n_samples - 1)
variable  x__abs_energy  ...  z__variation_coefficient
id                       ...                          
0           1430.496338  ...                  5.521904

[1 rows x 2274 columns]
C:/Users/Thund/Desktop/RepoBitbucket/Gaitrec/gaitrec/extraction.py:21: ConvergenceWarning: Number of distinct clusters (2) found smaller than n_clusters (2274). Possibly due to duplicate points in X.
  kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=self.n_features).fit(A_q)
[[1430.49633789   66.95824   ]]
[0, 1]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I don't understand the warnings and the cause that from 2k+ features it only extract the first 2,that's what I did:

1. Produce the covariance matrix from the original data
2. Compute eigenvectors and eigenvalues of the covariance matrix using the SVD method
3. Those two steps combined are what you call PCA.
   The Principle Components are the eigenvectors of the covariance matrix of the original data and then apply the K-means algorithm.

My question are:

1. How can I fix the warning it gives me?
2. It only select 2 features from 2k+ features, so something is wrong?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I don't understand the warnings and the cause that from 2k+ features it only extract the first 2

Comment: Not sure about the warning, but it looks like you're only selecting indices from the features that have been clustered with kmeans - and kmeans has been done on the output of PCA, which is reducing the number of dimensions. I think you're getting two features instead of q features because of the reshape of A_q (not certain), but the indices of the matrices aren't referring to the same things, so that should definitely be changed. self.features_ should probably come from A_q

Comment: @Elenchus Thank you for you answer. I implement the reshape in the euclidean distance cause I had trouble with this problem: https://dpaste.com/847AQ38PZ .

Comment: Ah, yes, so that's definitely why you're getting 2 features instead of 1. But the reshape isn't the real problem - A_q will only ever have as many features as there are dimensions coming out from the PCA. If you want more features, increase q. 2274 dimensions down to 1 is quite drastic, so maybe remove the reshape and limit q to a minimum of 2 while you're at it. But the features after the fit should come from A_q, not X

Comment: @Elenchus well I had to change the q to 1 cause I had another error that you can see here: https://dpaste.com/8USBE4FTP I just adapted from the errors I got.

Comment: But in doing so you've changed the intent of your code. From that error, seeing as you have lots of features to begin with, for min(n_samples, n_features) to be 1 you must only have 1 sample, which won't work. I should have noticed that before - [1 rows x 2274 columns]

Comment: @Elenchus what's the difference between n_samples and n_features ? as you can se I have a matrix 1(id=0) x 2000(features) , so why is not min(n_samples(1), n_features(which is 2k+)) ( should I add more ids? )

Comment: @Elenchus I just extracted some features from a csv, put it with one id and I need to extract the most significant features

Comment: min takes the minimum - so the smallest value between 1 and 2k+ is 1. n_samples is how many samples you have, in this case rows. So adding more features won't help. I'm not sure what the feature extraction function is doing, but it's turning your 1342 sample, 5 feature csv into a single sample.

Comment: @Elenchus this data is x,y,z from accelerometer sensor, so yeah I just wanna find some features and extract it to see which is the most relevant. So in this case, the rows should be every single tuple (x,y,z) from a singular walk, or each row should be for example if I have two walks: row= 0 (monday walk) row=1 (friday walk) ?

Comment: That probably warrants a new question. My guess would be the former, but really it depends what you're trying to do.

Comment: For each wallk extract a vector of significant features, simple as that, that's the reason I used one sample for one walk, is it correct?

Comment: I modify a bit the code, with two samples, the code go in a forever loop https://dpaste.com/6FAT7R54D in line 22

Comment: Update: seems with two samples it takes 20+ minutes to excute and extract a lot more features (with two samples, also I resolved the first warning) ** RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide
  explained_variance_ = (S ** 2) / (n_samples - 1)
variable  x__abs_energy  ...  z__variation_coefficient **

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, the features after the fit are coming from the indices of the A_q matrix, which has a reduced number of features from PCA. You're getting two features instead of q features (1 in this case) because of the reshape. self.features_ should probably come from A_q instead of X.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem in your code is in the following statement:

`pfa = PFA(n_features=2274, q=1)`

I haven't read the paper, but you have to observe `pca` behavior. If the authors set `q` variable to 1, you should see why `q` is 1.

For instance:

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import plot
from matplotlib.pyplot import xlabel
from matplotlib.pyplot import ylabel
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure

pca_obj = PCA().fit(X=X)
figure(1, figsize=(6,3), dpi=300)
plot(pca_obj.explained_variance_, linewidth=2)
xlabel('Components')
ylabel('Explained Variaces')
```

Note: If you are using an application other than `jupyter-notebook` please add `show` at the end of the line, in case you couldn't see any graph

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import plot
from matplotlib.pyplot import xlabel
from matplotlib.pyplot import ylabel
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure
from matplotlib.pyplot import show

pca_obj = PCA().fit(X=X)
figure(1, figsize=(6,3), dpi=300)
plot(pca_obj.explained_variance_, linewidth=2)
xlabel('Components')
ylabel('Explained Variaces')
show()
```

For my dataset,  the result is:

[image]

Now, I can say:  "My `q` variable is 100, since PCA performs better starting with 100 components."

Can say the same? How do you know `q` is 1?

Now observe your best `q` performance variable, see if it solves your problem.

Comment: I still don't understand how much components should I put. In the array I have and keep in mind what the 'errors' gave the PCA to me, is that the rows are the components(samples) in which case my data is formed like this: each row represent one walk and the columns are the features of the walk. So if I put the same rows as components, the array is identical(probably the pca sorts the array based on the variance), if I put less components probably it will try to sum some less significative features and give in output the array with less rows.

Comment: My code now is looking like this: https://dpaste.com/HKF8K5ZRN (I added more samples). When my code execute kmeans training, it will run so slow, and extract 2126 to 2289 features. How can I understand if is it correct or no for example? (I am trying to select some relevant features from 2289 features)

Comment: Before you use `PFA` you need to create a `pca` object, i.e. `pca_obj = PCA()`. Then you need to fit your `X`(data) to the declared `pca` object, i.e. `pca_obj.fit(X)`Then you need to plot and see the suitable number of component `plot(pca_obj.explained_variance_, linewidth=2)`

Comment: I don't see any window(graph) that opens with your code, why? `pca_obj = PCA() pca_obj.fit(extracted_features) figure(1, figsize=(6, 3), dpi=300) plot(pca_obj.explained_variance_, linewidth=2)`

Comment: I have got the result using `jupyter-notebook`. If you are using IDE like PyCharm or Spyder, you may need to add `show()` function. The `show()` fucntion can be implemented `from matplotlib.pyplot import show`

Comment: Thank you, the graph looks like this https://imgur.com/a/MCOLSCB so how much components should I get or there is some errors in my data?

Comment: I clicked on the link, but couldn't open.

Comment: I looked at the image and I think you could set `q = 20`. Hope it solves your problem.